# JavaScript Button Error

Tags: javascript, forms, function

The issue I have with my JavaScript is that when I select the "Send" button for a blank form, it tells me which fields to complete (which I want).  After selecting "OK", it asks me to "Please enter a valid email address." in another window.

Can anyone help me with the functions and logic to eliminate this second window if one selects "Send" without filling out the form?  Do I need to create a new function for "Entering a valid email address"?

Here's the code:

### javascript

```
function checkforblank() {
  var errormessage = "";
  if (document.getElementById('fname').value =="") {
    errormessage += "enter your first name \n";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('lname').value =="") {
    errormessage += "enter your last name \n";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('email').value =="") {
    errormessage += "enter your email \n";
  }
  if (document.getElementById('confirmEmail').value =="") {
    errormessage += "confirm your email \n";
  }

  if (errormessage != "") {
    alert(errormessage);
    return false;
  }
};

function verifyEmail() {
  var status = false;     
  var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  if (document.myForm.email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
    alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
  }
  else if (document.myForm.email.value != document.myForm.confirmEmail.value) {
    alert("Email addresses do not match.  Please retype them to make sure they are the same.");
  }
  else {
    alert("Thank you for your interest!");
    status = true;
  }
  return status;
}

function confirmEmailAddresses() {
  checkforblank();
  verifyEmail();
}
```

### html

```
<div id="content">
<form name="myForm" action="#" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="">
<table width="377" height="96">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">First Name:</td>
    <td><label for="FirstName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Last Name:</td>
    <td><label for="LastName"></label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right">Confirm E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="confirmEmail" id="confirmEmail"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="confirmEmailAddresses()"><input type="reset" value="Reset Form">

</form>
                </div>
```

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so please make this as easy as possible!  :)  Thank you.

Comment: `if ( !checkforblank() ) verifyEmail();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
function confirmEmailAddresses(){
    checkforblank();
    verifyEmail();
}
```

with

```
function confirmEmailAddresses(){

    if ( checkforblank() ) {
    verifyEmail();
    }
}
```

and add `else return true;` like so

```
if (errormessage != "") {
    alert(errormessage);
    return false;
  } else return true;
```

so `if` (in the `checkforblank()` function) `errormessage` is not (`!=`) empty (`""`) then `checkforblank()` tells the script (`return`s) `true` and `if` (in `confirmEmailAddresses()` now) **and only if** `checkforblank()` is truthy (`true` is kinda pretty truthy) then `verifyEmail()` is run, the end (`;`).  :p

Comment: Thank you so much!  That helped slightly, but it overrides the e-mail validation function.

Comment: @user2638775 ??? i thought you want to skip it (when other things also arent working), if i misunderstood your question, please explain and i will be glad to help you further.

Comment: When I fill out the form, and have mismatching email addresses, there is no validation.  :-\

Comment: @user2638775 im sorry i dont understand, you want a validation just no alert? then why the validation? do you want to send the e-mail only if it validates, and no alert anyway?

Comment: Your most recent edit from your initial response worked!  If the e-mails matched and were correctly formatted, then it would be a successful submission.  You and my friend rocked this problem!  Thank you!  :)  Now I just need to know why the data disappears when the information is mismatched.  haha!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
   function confirmEmailAddresses() {
      if(checkforblank() && verifyEmail())
         return true;
      else return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  But that isn't working either.  When the emails are mismatched and/or not present in the form, the submission is still successful, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

ok i think what your asking for is this (jquery)

```
$(":submit").click( function(event) {
      if(!checkforblank() || !verifyEmail()) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

if you do this *make sure to include **after** then button in the html*. or enclose in a `$(document).ready`

Comment: Does this prevent the info from disappearing in the fields when emails mismatch or are invalid?  Trying it, but having a hard time figuring out what order to place this in.

Comment: @user2638775 it prevents the form from being submitted, thats all, used with my previous answer it would look like `$(":submit").click( function(event) {checkforblank()?verifyEmail()?alert("good job!"):event.preventDefault():event.preventDefault();});` im not sure if its what you want and/or if you understand that code yet, but if it can help a bit thats good with me.

Comment: Everything is working!  You are amazing!  Now off to do the .php file.  :-\  I'm learning some of this from scratch.  The things that school does NOT teach you!

Comment: @user2638775 yep thats the way we roll (`?:` is a `if` operator just less cluttery) btw _when_ you reach 50 rep you can `+1` me, happy coding.